# remove characters from a c string

Tags: c

gcc 4.4.4 c89

I am reading in from a text file and the text file consists of names in double quotes.

```
"Simpson, Homer"
etc
```

However, I want to remove the double quotes from the string.

This is how I have done it, but I am not sure its the best way.

```
int get_string(FILE *in, char *temp)
{
    char *quote = NULL;
    /* Get the first line */
    fgets(temp, STRING_SIZE, in);
    printf("temp before [ %s ]\n", temp);
    /* Find the second quote */
    if((quote = strrchr(temp, '"')) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Text file incorrectly formatted\n");
        return FALSE;
    }
    /* Replace with a nul to get rid of the second quote */
    *quote = '\0';

    /* Move the pointer to point pass the first quote */
    temp++;
    printf("temp after [ %s ]\n", temp);
    return TRUE;
}
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this won't work. You are changing the parameter `temp`, but the calling function will still have an old value. The `temp` outside the function will point to the opening quote. You ought to move the characters in your buffer.

However I would suggest allocating the buffer in heap and returning a pointer to it, letting the caller free the buffer when needed. This seems to be a cleaner solution. Again, this way you won't rely on the caller to pass a sufficiently large buffer.

In general, a robust reading lines from a text file is not a trivial task in C, with its lack of automatic memory allocating functions. If possible to switch to C++, I would suggest trying much simpler C++ `getline`.

Comment: Alternatively, the OP can use `memmove(temp, temp + 1, strlen(temp + 1) + 1);` to shift the string within the buffer (instead of `temp++;`).

Comment: @caf: That is what I meant as "ought to move the characters in buffer".

Comment: Aye, I wasn't aiming the comment at you, more for the OP.

Comment: I used the following and decided to remove the first quote by overwriting it. memmove(temp - 1, temp, strlen(temp) + 1); Seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

```
char *foo(char *str, int notme)
{
    char *tmp=strdup(str);
    char *p, *q;
    for(p=str, q=tmp; *p; p++)
    {
       if((int)*p == notme) continue;
       *q=*p;
       q++;
    }
    strcpy(str, tmp);
    free(tmp);
    return str;
}
```

simple generic remove a char

Comment: If you could add *q = '\0'; after the end of the for loop it would fix the stale characters that will be present after removal of the delimiter. Apart from that, works fine.

Answer (score 2):

is *all* lines look that way why not simple remove the first and the last char?

```
quote++; // move over second char
quote[strlen(quote)-1]='\0'; // remove last char
```

Comment: same solution as mine, but using the same variable, great..ok mine would work even if string is const char* =P, +1 for being faster in answering

Comment: Because the last char is actually almost certainly a `\n`, since it was read with `fgets()` (but note that "second-last char" isn't good enough either, in case the last line in the file doesn't have a `\n`!)

Comment: ... and there may be trailing spaces to take care of.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose

> string="\"Simpson, Homer\""

then

> string_without_quotes=string+1;
>
> string_without_quotes[strlen(string)-2]='\0';

ready!

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this will help, it is a simple tokenizer i use

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int token(char* start, char* delim, char** tok, char** nextpos, char* sdelim, char* edelim) {
    // Find beginning:
    int len = 0;
    char *scanner;
    int dictionary[8];
    int ptr;

    for(ptr = 0; ptr < 8; ptr++) {
        dictionary[ptr] = 0;
    }

    for(; *delim; delim++) {
        dictionary[*delim / 32] |= 1 << *delim % 32;
    }

    if(sdelim) {
        *sdelim = 0;
    }

    for(; *start; start++) {
        if(!(dictionary[*start / 32] & 1 << *start % 32)) {
            break;
        }
        if(sdelim) {
            *sdelim = *start;
        }
    }

    if(*start == 0) {
        if(nextpos != NULL) {
            *nextpos = start;
        }
        *tok = NULL;
        return 0;
    }

    for(scanner = start; *scanner; scanner++) {
        if(dictionary[*scanner / 32] & 1 << *scanner % 32) {
            break;
        }
        len++;
    }

    if(edelim) {
        *edelim = *scanner;
    }

    if(nextpos != NULL) {
        *nextpos = scanner;
    }

    *tok = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));

    if(*tok == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }

    memcpy(*tok, start, len);
    *(*tok + len) = 0;


    return len + 1;
}
```

The parameters are:

- char* start, (pointer to the string)
- char* delim, (pointer to the delimiters used to break up the string)
- char** tok, a reference (using &) to a char* variable that will hold the toke
- char** nextpos, a reference (using &) to a char* variable that will hold the position after the last token.
- char* sdelim, a reference (using &) to a char variable that will hold the value of the -start delimiter
- char* edelim, a reference (using &) to a char varaible that will hold the value of the end delimiter

The last three are optional.

Pass in the start address, the delimeter is a ", and pass reference to a char * to hold the actual middle string.

The result is a newly allocated string so you have to free it.

```
int get_string(FILE *in, char *temp)
{
    char *token = NULL;
    /* Get the first line */
    fgets(temp, STRING_SIZE, in);
    printf("temp before [ %s ]\n", temp);
    /* Find the second quote */
    int length = token(temp, "\"", &token, NULL, NULL, NULL)

    // DO STUFF WITH THE TOKEN
    printf("temp after [ %s ]\n", token);
    // DO STUFF WITH THE TOKEN

    // FREE IT!!!
    free(token);
    return TRUE;
}
```

The tokenizer is a multipurpose tool that can be used in a crap ton of places, this being a very small example.

Comment: I know this is not the ideal usage of a tokenizer, but I feel its  a good tool to have around and can be used in many situations.